# Strange behavior of React setState with let variable change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below will render a `<h1>` and two `<button>`.

**In my expectation**, the `changeString1` `<button>` will change `letString` to `1` and change `<h1>` text to `1` finally, while the `changeString2` `<button>` will

1. change `<h1>` text to `3` **if I click the `changeString2` first**
2. change `<h1>` text to `1` **if I click the `changeString1` first**

But **in fact**

1. If I click the `changeString1` **once** first, then click the `changeString2`, **`<h1>` text will be `3`** ! But why?
2. **What's more**, if I click the `changeString1` **twice** first, then click the `changeString2`, **`<h1>` text will be `1`** ! But why?

It seems that both of 2 facts are contradictory...

You can test this by https://codesandbox.io/s/wy4l1y4o8

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  let letString = "3";
  const [statString, setStatString] = useState("2");

  function changeString1() {
    letString = "1";
    setStatString(letString);
  }

  function changeString2() {
    console.log(letString);
    setStatString(letString);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{statString}</h1>
      <button onClick={changeString1}>changeString1</button>
      <button onClick={changeString2}>changeString2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I think you found an artifact. Advice like "don't use local variable" would solve your case but it doesn't answer the question why it stays "1" after two clicks. Theoretically, it shouldn't get stuck at "1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at the flow that is taking place:-

```
1st click on changeString1

state changes

component re renders

letString gets re-initialized to 3 because of let letString = "3"

value of letString = 3;
value of statString = 1 (state);

2nd click on changeString1

value of letString gets set to 1 in the function call;

But value of statString(state) is already 1 so no state changes and component never re-renders and letString is not re-initialized

After 2nd click values are:-

letString = 1;
statString = 1(state);

Now, when you click on changeString2 value of letString is 1 and statString is also 1 so state doesn't changes and nothing happens and you just see 1.
```

Comment: This makes sense. I have tried to add the thrid button named `changeString3` which calls a function executes `setStatString("4");`. After I clicke twice `changeString1` and click once `changeString3`, click once `changeString2` finally results to `<h1>` text be `3` again. So the key point is, if a component doesn't need to re-render, its local variables will not be re-initial?

Comment: Yeah you got it. When a component isn’t re rendered, letString does not re initiate and remains as it is. But not in the case of state. State is only initialized once when component mounts and not on further re renders.

Answer (score 1):

You should track clicking on changeString1 in a separate variable:

```js
const {useState} = React

function App() {
  const [statString, setStatString] = useState("2");
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

  function changeString1() {
    setClicked(true)
    setStatString("1");
  }

  function changeString2() {
    setStatString(clicked ? "1" : "3");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{statString}</h1>
      <button onClick={changeString1}>changeString1</button>
      <button onClick={changeString2}>changeString2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

The reason your code didn't work as expected is that each invocation of `App` creates a new instance of the `letState` variable that is bound to `changeString2` function when it is *defined*. 
React optimizes calls that don't change the state, avoiding unnecessary re-renders. So when you click the second time you are not causing a replacements of the callback functions. So when you click on `changeState2` it's the same function defined in "previous" render.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on **changeString2**, local variable **letString** value is 3.

If you want to persist **letString** value between render cycles you must use **useState** or even using a global scope variable (not recommended)

Comment: but why in fact 2, I click on changeString2 results to <h1> text be 1?

Comment: If you place console.log('rendering', letString) just before the return of the function, you will see that letString value is always '3' when rendering. It doesn't matter that you change it inside the changeString1 local function, when the component is about to render itself, letString is initialized again to 3.